# メールを受信した際に文字化け

Tags: php, 文字化け, encoding

受信メールの本文が下の画像のようになってしまいます。どのようにすれば受信メールの文字がおかしくならないでしょうか？

#### コード

```php
<?php
 mb_language("Japanese");
 mb_internal_encoding("UTF-8");
 $mail_to = "<宛先メールアドレス>";
 $mail_subject = "オークションで車を売るでお問い合わせ";
 $mail_body = "希望価格".$_POST["kakaku"]."\n車種".$_POST["syasyu"]."\n購入方法".$_POST["houhou"]."\nお名前".$_POST["name"]."\n電話番号".$_POST["tel"]."\nメールアドレス".$_POST["mail"]."\n郵便番号".$_POST["yubin"]."\n住所".$_POST["jusyo"]."\n備考".$_POST["bikou"];
 $mail_header = "from：".$mail;
 ?>
```

#### 受信メール

[image: 受信メールの本文]

Comment: スタック・オーバーフローへようこそ！コードをコメントに記述すると、改行やシンタックスハイライティングが有効にならなず非常に読みにくくなってしまうため、質問の本文に記載するようにお願いします。

Comment: 無知で済みません。以後気を付けます。ありがとうございます。

Comment: こんな記事＆サンプル [【MailForm01】PHP多機能メールフォーム　フリー（無料）版](https://www.php-factory.net/mail/01.php) を参考にしてみては？

Comment: コメント欄のコードは本文にも転記されているのと、メールアドレスが含まれているので念のため削除しておきます。 / また、本文の方のメールアドレス部分も(恐らく伏せ字にする目的で)書き換えられていますが、第三者が使っているとも限らないので修正しておきました。

Comment: メールは何のメーラー(Thunderbird、Outlook、gmail等のWebメール画面上など)を使って確認したでしょうか？

Comment: メールの件名や送信先、本文を指定する部分はありますが、肝心のメールを送信する部分がないので想像に過ぎないのですが、もしかして、[mail関数](https://www.php.net/manual/ja/function.mail.php)で送信していますか？もしそうだとすると、文字化けする可能性があるため、1度[mb_send_mail関数](https://www.php.net/manual/ja/function.mb-send-mail.php)での送信を試してみていただけないでしょうか。ちなみに、エンコードをきちんとしてやれば、mail関数でも送信できるのですが、手っ取り早く治したいということであれば、mb_send_mail関数のほうが楽だと思います。的外れでしたら申し訳ないですが。

Comment: mb_send_mail関数を使ってメールを送信してみたところ、文字も日本語で表記されました。しかし、selectタグとtextareaタグがメールでは空白になってしまいました。メーラーはgmailです。

Comment: もしかして、フォーム側のname属性で指定している文字列とPHP側の「$_POST」で取得している文字列が違うということはないでしょうか。試しに、「var_dump($_POST);」でポストされてきたデータを見てみると何か解決のヒントになるかもしれないですが、どうでしょうか。

Comment: 文字化けについては解決したのであればこの質問自体は解決済みとして新しい質問として登録したほうが良いかと思います。